# Move an app to SD Card

Tags: android

I have a problem moving my application to the SD Card , I learnt to enable an app to move to the SD card , i need to take care of two important things

1. min SDK must be greater than or equal to 10
2. set android:installLocation="auto" in android manifest , I learnt that doing that android :installLocation="auto" will do the job than setting it to External

My problem is that Whenever i have an app whose size is less than 50 Mb this works fine , But if the size of the app exceeds more than that, I receive an error stating that "Not enough size in SD card" , I checked my SD card and I am sure that it had enough space to accomodate the app ! what could be the problem and suggest me some possible solutions which would help me !